# numpy to generate discrete probability distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm following a code example I found at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html#subclassing-rv-discrete for implementing a random number generator for discrete values of a normal distribution. The exact example (not surprisingly) works quite well, but if I modify it to allow only left or right-tailed results, the distribution around 0 should is too low (bin zero should contain more values). I must have hit a boundary condition, but am unable to work it out. Am I missing something?

This is the result of counting the random numbers per bin:

```
np.bincount(rvs) [1082 2069 1833 1533 1199  837  644  376  218  111   55   20   12    7    2 2]
```

This is the histogram:

[image]

```
from scipy import stats

np.random.seed(42)

def draw_discrete_gaussian(rng, tail='both'):
    # number of integer support points of the distribution minus 1
    npoints = rng if tail == 'both' else rng * 2
    npointsh = npoints / 2
    npointsf = float(npoints)
    # bounds for the truncated normal
    nbound = 4
    # actual bounds of truncated normal
    normbound = (1+1/npointsf) * nbound
    # integer grid
    grid = np.arange(-npointsh, npointsh+2, 1)
    # bin limits for the truncnorm
    gridlimitsnorm = (grid-0.5) / npointsh * nbound
    # used later in the analysis
    gridlimits = grid - 0.5
    grid = grid[:-1]
    probs = np.diff(stats.truncnorm.cdf(gridlimitsnorm, -normbound, normbound))
    gridint = grid

    normdiscrete = stats.rv_discrete(values=(gridint, np.round(probs, decimals=7)), name='normdiscrete')
    # print 'mean = %6.4f, variance = %6.4f, skew = %6.4f, kurtosis = %6.4f'% normdiscrete.stats(moments =  'mvsk')
    rnd_val = normdiscrete.rvs()
    if tail == 'both':
        return rnd_val
    if tail == 'left':
        return -abs(rnd_val)
    elif tail == 'right':
        return abs(rnd_val)


rng = 15
tail = 'right'
rvs = [draw_discrete_gaussian(rng, tail=tail) for i in xrange(10000)]

if tail == 'both':
    rng_min = rng / -2.0
    rng_max = rng / 2.0
elif tail == 'left':
    rng_min = -rng
    rng_max = 0
elif tail == 'right':
    rng_min = 0
    rng_max = rng

gridlimits = np.arange(rng_min-.5, rng_max+1.5, 1)
print gridlimits
f, l = np.histogram(rvs, bins=gridlimits)

# cheap way of creating histogram
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

bins, edges = f, l
left,right = edges[:-1],edges[1:]
X = np.array([left, right]).T.flatten()
Y = np.array([bins, bins]).T.flatten()

# print 'rvs', rvs
print 'np.bincount(rvs)', np.bincount(rvs)

plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Looking at the graph, it seems to me like bin 0 contains everything from -0.5 to 0.5. If so, it's not surprising that it's about half the next bin; you're not generating results from the left half of that bin.

Comment: @user2357112: I could be wrong, but I think this is only due to the visualisation (it centres around the bin number whereas in fact the bin is bounded by +0.5). It's the same graph if I do `gridlimits = np.arange(rng_min, rng_max+2, 1)`.

Comment: I also think @user235711 is right. When you take the abs, you are combining the negative and positive bins of probs. Check that the length of the bin that starts at zero has the same combined length as the other bins. I would just take the correct truncated normal for right or left, i.e. starting or ending at zero.

Comment: Both of what you say sounds convincing (although I thought I got around this half-split bin 0 by multiplying the number of support points `npoints = rng if tail == 'both' else rng * 2`)...

Comment: I might have found a solution thanks to both your comments - thanks for your help (+1x2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to answer my own question based on comments from @user333700 and @user235711:

I insert into the method before `normdiscrete = ...`

```
if tail == 'right':
    gridint = gridint[npointsh:]
    probs = probs[npointsh:]
    s = probs.sum()
    probs = probs / s
elif tail == 'left':
    gridint = gridint[0: npointsh]
    probs = probs[0: npointsh]
    s = probs.sum()
    probs = probs / s
```

The resulting histograms[image] and [image]look much nicer: